# Can you get more information about the online file?

Tags: python

I have a online file: http://dl_dir.qq.com/qqfile/tm/TM2009Beta_chs.exe ,please donot download it, i want to determine the software version  whether is changed, so i want more information about it. for example, using python,i can get this:

```
import urllib2,urllib
req = urllib2.Request('http://dl_dir.qq.com/qqfile/tm/TM2009Beta_chs.exe')        
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print response.info()
print response.geturl()

Content-Length: 16868680
Server: qqdlsrv(1.84 for linux)
Connection: close
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=TM2009Beta_chs.exe
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

http://dl_dir.qq.com/qqfile/tm/TM2009Beta_chs.exe
```

Can you get more imformation to let me determine the software version is changed?

Comment: That is almost **the** most effective way to waste your bandwidth.  For maximum efficiency, I suggest posting on 4chan "Hey guys bandwidth is expensive don't download this file."

Comment: Apart from the URL, exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253282/how-can-i-get-the-file-version-on-the-internet-but-not-download-it

Answer (score 4):

1. Download the first thousand bytes or so of the file using the range header.
2. Use [pefile](http://code.google.com/p/pefile/) to parse the PE header and extract version information.
3. With the data, [extract useful information](http://books.google.com/books?id=Pas0YoxygnkC&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=pe+header+layout&source=bl&ots=QmWK2D3niq&sig=FEWTlTHlaukrlQ-mHybNqW81BjY&hl=en&ei=LuGASpnPH42YsgOj5JH9CA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3#v=onepage&q=pe%20header%20layout&f=false) such as the time date stamp and other goodies that let you find changes in files without reading the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all kinds of information about an EXE Windows file if you download it (the easy way, by running external utilities on it, or up to a point the hard way, via APIs and your own code simulating those utilities) -- a lot depends on what info was put into it when it was built. Without downloading, you can get only the info the server is giving you, which in this case seems pretty scarce -- I can't believe that server's configured to NOT tell you latest modified date &c. In your shoes, I'd see what can be done on the server side to remedy that dearth of info, so you don't have to download the EXE just to find out more!

Answer (score 2):

Configure your server to provide a [Last-Modified](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29) header, and use [If-Modified-Since](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25) in your request.